# Is it possible to install developing app to another android device by sharing the apk file?

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have been trying to install my app into another android device. I am developing the app using Android Studio in java where I used user location access permission. During development, build the app in my phone and it is working fine. When I share my apk file to another device by ShareIt and then try to install it says **'App not installed.'**

minSdkVersion is 16
targetSdkVersion is 28

package name is unique and there has no older version in device.

Also allow 'Unknown sources' option in device

So in this scenario is it possible to install?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create the apk file? You should use the Android Studio "Build APK" function

Comment: You probably try to install Debug version which is not possible. You must generate Release APK the way previous comment says

Comment: If you got the app by directly running from android studio then it will not work if you share the apk using ShareIt . You have to build the apk and use the apk .

Answer (score 1):

you should build a debug Apk or set                 debuggable true

```
android {

    //...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        customDebuggableBuildType {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

   //...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even is dev mode you can generate signed apk, i think in this way apk is secure and it can be installed by os. 
You have to make a key store . 
After you make the apk (make sure you increase the version code ) put it on a drive or something (gmail does not allow to send apk attached ) open the link on that phone and install . ->Build generate signed apk
Make sure on that phone it is checked from settings : Install apps from Unknown sources.
I think that since last year all apks have to be signed so they can be installed